# Is there an endpoint/way to GET the tls certificate used in https?

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.3

From my understanding, TLS requires a certificate which is validated on the client side to assert trust between the client and the server, so that an encrypted channel may be opened up.

For https this trusted certificate is retrieved via http (which is why we don't have to download a facebook.com.crt manually to access https://facebook.com).

Right now I have an issue where I need to implement amqps and mqtts through an ingress, and I don't know how to distribute the certificate to the external parties without manually emailing them the certificate (which won't work, obviously).

Is there an endpoint/way to get the certificate used in https, so that I can later use that for mqtts/amqps? The same way that http -> certificate -> https, I mean.

Comment: *"For https this trusted certificate is retrieved via http"* - No. The certificate is part of the TLS handshake (part of HTTPS), not accessed by HTTP.  And it is not considered trusted until it is  validated against the local trust store. There is no need to download and propagate the server certificate to other systems. I'm proposing to close this question because it is based on false assumptions of how TLS/HTTPS and certificates work.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I agree on closing question.